# Compilation issue in Magento

Tags: magento, compilation, extension-methods

When I enable the `compilation` from Magento admin then the product is deleted from admin, the checkout page is not working and store locater extension page `http://demo.azurigroup.com.au/ponicosmetics/index.php/storelocator/index/` is working. But if I disable the compilation then my extension page http://demo.azurigroup.com.au/ponicosmetics/index.php/storelocator/index/ is not working.

Please suggest to me what I should do.

Comment: Enable error reporting .. As currently it is showing blank screen

Comment: This error comes Fatal error: Call to a member function getTemplate() on a non-object in /sites/azuri/ponicosmetics/app/code/community/EM/Em0122settings/Helper/Data.php on line 29 Call Stack: 0.0015 664624 1. {main}() /sites/azuri/ponicosmetics/index.php:0 0.0082 1230408 2. Mage::run() /sites/azuri/ponicosmetics/index.php:88 0.0259 3059480 3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /sites/azuri/ponicosmetics/app/Mage.php:684 1.6957 17344904 4.Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() /sites/azuri/ponicosmetics/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354 1.7081 17821512

Comment: when i enable errors from index file